# Would I still be able to cast the Conjure Barrage spell if I was also using the Flame Arrow spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranged-attack, spellcasting

*Conjure barrage* specifies that the ammunition used to cast it must be non magical but I can't find anywhere if an arrow under the effect of *flame arrow* is considered magical or not.

What I mean by that is, is the arrow in and of itself magical or does *flame arrow* just set it on fire as it's launched as though it had been wrapped in cloth soaked in oil and lit (but without those steps)?

Would I still be able to use it as a medium to cast the *conjure barrage* spell or would I not be able to cast that till I lost concentration on *flame arrow*/the spell ran its course? If not, would the effects stack?

Comment: Hi Rockon5002, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work, and visit the [help] for more guidance. I've tried to split up the text a little, but feel free to [edit] your question if you don't like my changes.

Answer (score 21):

### You can use arrows treated with Conjure Barrage, but the effects won't stack

**Conjure Barrage** requires no concentration, so that is not a concern when casting it during **Flame Arrows**. Conjure Barrage requires the weapon or ammunition used to be non-magical, but nowhere in the rules text does it state that Flame Arrows turns the arrows magical (while other spells, eg. **Shillelagh**, do --- the exception therefore proving the rule).

However, the Flame Arrows only deal extra damage "when a target is hit by a ranged weapon attack using a piece of ammunition drawn from the quiver". Conjure Barrage is not a ranged weapon attack, or an attack at all --- it is instead resolved as a saving throw. Therefore the barrage deals normal damage even if you use arrows enchanted with Flame Arrows.

Comment: Thank you I thought that might be the case but I wasn't certain I didn't really expect the effects to stack though it would be nice if they did I just wasn't sure if one would block me from casting the other.